# GitHub desktop merge from master button disabled

Tags: github

**GitHub desktop merge from master button disabled.**

It was working before. My colleagues have created new branches etc... but my update button is disabled. Weird.

Any help will be appreciable.

edit: A link to the screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0awxr7q1jzl9y7s/Screenshot%202017-08-14%2009.41.02.png?dl=0

Comment: not enough context to answer this question. post a screenshot or something to describe the problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

The button is disabled because there are are no new commits on the `master` branch. What that button does, is updates your current branch (in your case `bugfix/portraitPositionOffset`) with any new commits on the branch it is being compared to - in your case, the `master` branch.

If your colleagues have pushed new work to other branches, it probably doesn't need to be merged into your current bugfix branch. When the bugfix branch is eventually merged into master, and their branches are merged into master, all of the work will get combined together.